# Polyglossia in italian has problems with commands that requires "

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, polyglossia

Given this preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
```

I try to compile (XeLaTeX) this TikZ picture:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.5pt, >=latex, scale=2]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \path (O)++(0,4) coordinate ["left:$y$"] (y);
  \draw [-stealth, thin] (O)--++(4,0) coordinate ["below:$x$"] (x);
  \draw [stealth- , thin](y) -- (O);
  \draw [thin] (-0.5,0) -| (0,-0.5);
  \coordinate (v1) at (1.5,2);
  \path (2,0.5) coordinate (v2) ++(v1) coordinate (I);
  \path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red] (O)--(v1)--(I)--(v2)--(O);
  \draw [->] (O)--(v1); \draw [dashed, ->] (v1)--(I);
  \draw [->] (O)--(v2); \draw [dashed, ->] (v2)--(I);
  \node [anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] at (v2) {${
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{12} \\ a_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}
  }$};
  \node [anchor=south east, font=\footnotesize] at (v1) {${
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} \\ a_{21}
  \end{bmatrix}
  }$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I get the following error:

```
./submit tex stack.tex:14: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"left:$y$"' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I think that it is due to how polyglossia handles " " in italian. I tried to get rid of it by switching to:

```
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
```

but then I can't compile (literally, the gears in the GUI don't stop), so I get no report of this. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is `["left:$y$"]` good syntax? I get the same error even without polyglossia.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I also need `quotes`  (I used it in the original document, but when I posted here I removed everything that wasn't needed, and I accidentally removed that too, sorry!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you use requires also the `quotes` library. You should also load the `babel` library.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,quotes,babel}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.5pt, >=latex, scale=2]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \path (O)++(0,4) coordinate ["left:$y$"] (y);
  \draw [-stealth, thin] (O)--++(4,0) coordinate ["below:$x$"] (x);
  \draw [stealth- , thin](y) -- (O);
  \draw [thin] (-0.5,0) -| (0,-0.5);
  \coordinate (v1) at (1.5,2);
  \path (2,0.5) coordinate (v2) ++(v1) coordinate (I);
  \path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red] (O)--(v1)--(I)--(v2)--(O);
  \draw [->] (O)--(v1); \draw [dashed, ->] (v1)--(I);
  \draw [->] (O)--(v2); \draw [dashed, ->] (v2)--(I);
  \node [anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] at (v2) {${
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{12} \\ a_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}
  }$};
  \node [anchor=south east, font=\footnotesize] at (v1) {${
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} \\ a_{21}
  \end{bmatrix}
  }$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works actually! Just notice, just in case this can be helpful to anyone in future, that `usetikzlibrary(babel)` **MUST** be loaded **before** `\setdefaultlanguage`. Once again: thanks!